# recarca de pagina en ionic 7, no se recarga la pagina anterior

Tags: typescript, ionic, ionic-framework

estroy realizando una aplicacion con ionic 7, el problema surge cuando navego a la pagina anterior, no con ion-back-button sino con route.navigation, la pagina anterior toma las funciones de carga de datos que estan en el constructor, no en todas las vistas sucede, y cuando realizo alguna actualizacion de datos en la pagina que corresponde y luego retorno a la vista anterior donde estas listado, no hay una recarga de la información.

1- cuando creo la ficha tecnica/mecanica, al momento de regresar al detalle del vehiculo, no desaparce el boton de crear ficha

2- y cuando navego del detalle a la lista de inspecciones, no se recarga, ya que hay una validacion desde el backend que solo envie los autos que no han sido inspeccionados.

Gracias de ante mano.

fragmento de app.routes

```
{
path: 'mechanic',
loadChildren: () => import('./home-mechanic/home-mechanic.module').then( 
m => m.HomeMechanicPageModule)
},
{
path: 'inspections',
loadChildren: () => import('./inspections/inspections.module').then( m 
=> m.InspectionsPageModule)
},
{
path: 'mechanical-file/:id',
loadChildren: () => import('./mechanical-file/mechanical- 
file.module').then( m => m.MechanicalFilePageModule)
},
{
path: 'car-detail/:id/:route',
loadChildren: () => import('./car-detail/car-detail.module').then( m => 
m.CarDetailPageModule)
},
{
path: 'car-detail/:id/:route/:category',
loadChildren: () => import('./car-detail/car-detail.module').then( m => 
m.CarDetailPageModule)
},
{
path: 'car-detail-mechanic/:id/:route',
loadChildren: () => import('./car-detail-mechanic/car-detail- 
mechanic.module').then( m => m.CarDetailMechanicPageModule)
},
{
path: 'home-admin',
loadChildren: () => import('./home-admin/home-admin.module').then( m => 
m.HomeAdminPageModule)
},
```

inspections.ts

```
public goBack(){
 this.router.navigate(['mechanic']);
}

public goTo(id:any){
 this.router.navigate(['car-detail-mechanic/'+id+'/inspections']);
}

public getInspections(){
 let data = {
  id_mechanic: this.id_mechanic!
 }
 this.utils.presentLoading("Cargando...");
 this.mechanicSrv.getInspections(data).subscribe(
  (data:any) => {

    if (data.status) {
      this.arrayInspections = data.data;
      this.utils.dismissLoading();
    }else{
      this.utils.dismissLoading();
      this.utils.presentToast("Sin inspecciones para realizar");
    }

  },
  (error) => {
    console.log(error);
    this.utils.dismissLoading();
    this.utils.presentToast("Error de servidor");
  }
 )

}
```

Detailcar.ts

```
 goBack(){
 if(this.theRoute == "home-mechanic"){
  this.router.navigate(['mechanic']);
 }else
 if(this.theRoute == "inspections"){
  this.router.navigate(['inspections']);
 }
 }

 public openFile() {
 this.router.navigate(['add-mechanic- 
 file/'+this.id_vehicle.id+'/'+this.theRoute]);
 }
 public getVehicleById(){
 this.utils.presentLoading("Cargando");
 this.mechanicSrv.getVehicleById(this.id_vehicle).subscribe(
  (res: any) => {
    if(res.status){
      console.log(res.data)
      this.carDetail = res.data
      this.utils.dismissLoading();
    }else{
      this.utils.dismissLoading();
      this.utils.presentToast("Error al cargar el vehiculo");
    }
  },
  (err) => {
    console.log(err);
    this.utils.dismissLoading();
    this.utils.presentToast("Error al cargar el vehiculo");
  }
  );
  }

  public mechanicalFileDetail(){
  this.router.navigate(['mechanical-file-detail- 
  mechanic/'+this.id_vehicle.id+'/'+this.theRoute]);
  }
```

createmechfile.ts

```
goBack(){
this.router.navigate(['/car-detail- 
mechanic/'+this.id_vehicle+'/'+this.theRoute]);
}

 public saveMechanicalFile(){

if(this.newMechanicalFile.air_conditioning_system === "" || 
this.newMechanicalFile.air_conditioning_system === undefined){
  this.utils.presentToast("El campo sistema de aire acondicionado es 
  requerido");
  return;
}



 if(this.newMechanicalFile.general_condition === "" || 
 this.newMechanicalFile.general_condition === undefined){

  this.utils.presentToast("El campo Condicion general es requerido")
  return;
 }


 this.mechanicSrv.addMechanicalFile(this.newMechanicalFile)
  .subscribe((res:any) => {
  this.utils.presentLoading("Creando ficha mecanica")
  if (res.status) {
    this.utils.dismissLoading()
    this.utils.presentToast("Se ha creado la ficha mecanica 
   correctamente")
    this.goBack();
    this.newMechanicalFile.part_emblems_complete = "";
  
    this.newMechanicalFile.general_condition = "";
   }else{
    this.utils.dismissLoading()
    this.utils.presentToast("Ha ocurrido un error al crear la ficha 
    mecanica")
   }
   }
   ,(err) => {
  this.utils.dismissLoading()
  this.utils.presentToast("Ha ocurrido un error al crear la ficha 
   mecanica")
   }
  )
 }
```

Comment: *"Hago esto, hago lo otro y pasa X"*... sin ver el código, eso es todo lo que entendemos. Tú crees que podemos ayudarte con esa explicación?? Te recomiendo usar el enlace [edit] y añadir el código necesario para reproducir tu problema (un [mre] vamos). Si no, es imposible ayudarte.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

buenas encontre la solucion al problema de la recarga de la vista, utilice la funtcion ionViewWillEnter(), la cual usaba cuando programaba en Ionic 3, creo que en ionic 7, no hay recarga de la vista cada vez que uno hace un navigation back, con el back button, aqui les dejo la solución la cual es ionViewWillEnter().